# Magento 2.3.4 to 2.4 after upgrade product can't save showing error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Bellow error showing I did do an update on schedule, setup upgrade, cache clean reindex, give root user try everything but still get this issue on product saves.
The Bellow problem is showing when I try to save the product from the admin pannel.

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'm24.scconnector_google_feed_cl' doesn't exist, query was: DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` WHERE (value_id = 630 AND entity_id = 640 AND store_id = 0)
```

I did try bellow code:

```
php bin/magento cron:install
php bin/magento cron:run
php bin/magento index:reindex
mysql -u root -p set global log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_GoogleShoppingAds
```

I didn't see scconnector_google_feed_cl can anyone tell why this table not showing after migrate from Magento 2.3.4 to 2.4?

Can anyone give me the SQL for creating this scconnector_google_feed_cl so I can create it?

Comment: Hi, you have found any solution for this? I have the same issue. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In magento 2.4 GoogleShoppingAds is removed. But there is still a database trigger on the update, insert and delete of an entity.

On the table 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value' you have 3 triggers, just delete them to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I had the same error, I'm running 2.3.5-p2 and after reading your answer I did not know how to delete the triggers, so I duplicated the table *catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value* without duplicating the triggers (using sql client sqlyog) and that fixed the product saving issue for me. Would appreciate it if you could show the proper way to delete the triggers. +1 Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The tables ending by `_cl` are tables created for "Update by schedule" indexes.

So in "System > Index Management", maybe try to put your "Google Product Feed" index from "update by schedule" to "on save", and then put it to "Update by schedule" again.

Comment: There is no google product feed index on my site what i do to ger it back?

Comment: You disabled the module `Magento_GoogleShoppingAds`. You'll find it if you're enable the module again. (but it's weird that you still have the error if you disabled the module and cleared the cache)

Comment: After migrate to magento 2.3.4 to magento 2.4 its showing..

In AbstractIndexerManageCommand.php line 43:

  The following requested index types are not supported: 'scconnector_google_feed'.
  Supported types: design_config_grid, customer_grid, catalog_category_product, catalog_product_category, catalogrule_rule, catalog
  _product_attribute, cataloginventory_stock, inventory, catalogrule_product, catalog_product_price, catalogsearch_fulltext


indexer:reindex [<index>...]

There is no information in google about it can you help me about it?