# scconnector_google_feed_cl error after product save (just upgraded to 2.3.5-p2)

Tags: magento2.3, database, magento-upgrade

I just upgraded Magento to 2.3.5-p2, now I'm getting the following error after saving products:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mg2.mg_scconnector_google_feed_cl' doesn't exist, query was: UPDATE `mg_catalog_product_entity_decimal` SET `value` = ? WHERE (entity_id = 204) AND (attribute_id = '77') AND (`store_id` = '0')
```

Any ideas why this table does not exist and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I hit the problem also after when I've updated to 2.3.5-p2. During my investigation, I've found out that the problem was caused by the indexer from the "Google Product Feed" module. After a deep dive into the mechanics of indexes and how are they organized, I've found a simple solution.

All you need to do is go to:

> Admin area -> System -> Tools -> Index Management

And look for the **Google Product Feed**

Select this row and, in the mass action widget above, select "Update by Schedule". After that, a proper table (scconnector_google_feed_cl) should be created in your database. If you had already selected "Update by schedule" for this indexer, then select "Update on Save" and after that, you can switch back to the "Update by Schedule". This should solve your problem.

If you want to dive deeper into the reason for this problem, you can read about it here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/indexing.html#m2devgde-mview

I hope it will help :)

Regards,
Artur

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem as well. [Check this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/322249/90298) - it's the right one. You have to delete all the triggers in your database that reference 'scconnector_google_feed_cl'. There's three for each of the catalog_product_entity_*** tables.

You can go into phpmyadmin and select your database, then Triggers to see them all on one page.
[image]
(in my case it was all of them)